# Problem with text marker

Tags: html, text

I have a problem with my website, and that is when i visit it and click somewhere a BIG text marker is shown at the side.

Visit the site urself and check?

[The website](http://habhut.se/hemligthaha/)

Just visit and click somewhere and u can see what the problem is. How do i fix this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Same... I can't see anything strange. Firefox 3.5.2, Vista.

Comment: Also - to the two people who have marked this as spam, it's clearly not. It's a page with non-functioning links and lorem ipsum text.

Comment: failed to reproduce. Firefox 3.0.14, XP

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Firefox, you may have it set to "[Caret Mode](http://clickspeak.clcworld.net/faq.html#caret)" - press F7 to disable.

I tried it on your site, and got a big black bar on the side as you reported.

I discovered Caret Mode the hard way myself: when you hit F7 it asks you to confirm that you want to switch - both the pressing F7 and the confirmation were done by my cat on the keyboard (!) and I couldn't figure out what had screwed up my browser...

Comment: I can confirm this. I didnt have that line until i pressed F7 and then when i focused my browser - there it was. Just use arrow keys to move it...

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the large block of text that stays at the bottom? That appears in the HTML like anything else and appears when I load the page. I don't see anything else appearing when I click around.

More details?

*P.S. I would have made this a comment if I had the rep points to do so... :-/*

Answer (score 0):

I took a printscreen on the issue to show you more clearly what I mean appears.

Here is it. I am using Firefox 3.5.3

http://i28.tinypic.com/2gse9mw.png

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you have "Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages" enabled in Firefox.